# For which value of a does the interval $\left[0,\frac{1}{3}\right]$ completely include the function f(x)

Tags: functions

For which value of $a$ does the interval $\left[0,\frac{1}{3}\right]$ completely include the range of the function 
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{3x^4-8ax^3+12a^2 + x^2+a}
$$

Comment: What have you tried? I'd say that we are interested in finding the range of the function in a general case, for any value of $a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A beginning:

You want that ${1\over f(x)}\geq3$, or that
$$g(x):=3x^4-8ax^3+x^2+12a^2+a-3\geq0\qquad(-\infty<x<\infty)\ .$$
This $g$ is a polynomial of degree $4$ satisfying $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}g(x)=\infty$. Therefore $g$ has one stationary point $\xi$ or three stationary points  $\xi_1<\xi_2<\xi_3$  (depending on $a$) that you can compute. The points $\xi$, resp. $\xi_1$ and $\xi_3$, will be local minima. If the values of $g$ at $\xi$, resp. at $\xi_1$ and $\xi_3$, are $\geq3$ you are in good shape.

Unfortunately the discussion in terms of $a$ leads to complicated computations. The following figure shows $g$ as a function of $x$ and $a$. In the dark blue region $g$ is negative. One can see that for $a\approx-0.75$ and $a\approx 0.55$ the function $x\mapsto g(x,a)$ is always positive.

[image]